# Hide a part of website when viewing by mobile

Tags: javascript, html

in my template html I would like to hide some content in

tag to users who view the website by using their mobile phones. Can we do that with javascript and how? Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some (simplified) code to show us what you've got so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). People usually do something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .hidden_mobile {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Using the media query above, an element will be hidden if it has the class `hidden_mobile` and the screen size is less than `480px` - [**example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/V2TSW/). You would therefore just add this class to all the elements you want hidden on mobile devices.

---

It's worth noting that you should have a viewport set if you expect this to work on mobile devices.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```